# Which devices can I develop for using the Nokia API Bridge for Flash Lite?

Tags: api, symbian, nokia, flashlite

I need to develop a mobile application that connects to the devices camera and to a remote server.
Using the Nokia API Bridge for Flash Lite which devices can I target? Does anyone know if this API works with any Symbian 60 device or only for 3rd edition? Do I need to publish as Flash Lite 3? can I publish Flash Lite 2?

What about KuneriLite, can this still be used with Flash Lite 3 given the security restriction for Flash Lite 3 ([see here](http://device54.com/blog/2007/12/flash-lite-3-security.html))

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had confirmation from Nokia forum that the Nokia API Bridge only works with Symbian Series 60 3rd Edition and greater. There are phones that are Symbian Series 60 3rd Edition that support both Flash Lite 2 and 3.